# My Android App won't read data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made an App on Android Studio also using Google Firebase.
When I insert data in the Database it works just fine, but when I want to retrieve the data and read it on a list the app crashes.

This is the function:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseFilms.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            filmsList.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot filmSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Films film = filmSnapshot.getValue(Films.class);
                filmsList.add(film);
            }

            FilmList adapter = new FilmList(Profile.this, filmsList);
            listViewFilms.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Please mention crash details also.

Comment: Have you initialised `filmsList` and `listViewFilms`?

Comment: Try look at my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44770581/5703820
Thumbs up if it's help you.

Comment: *filmSnapshot.getValue(Films.class)* is probably the issue. A snapshot won't have any *Films.class* children.

Comment: were u able to solve this problem? I am facing it too.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that Films.class properties and Firebase child properties is the same .
also you can read android studio console to know more about the error

Comment: This is really not correct. Firebase has no sense of Films.class and even if the properties were the same, Firebase API doesn't read in classes; only Strings, Numbers and Bools (and an Array).