# Add number of logins by user on firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Im new to firebase and I want to add number of logins done by each user in database separate for each user. How do I add this and update it each time the user logs in.
CreateAccount activity

```
public class CreateAccount extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText rEmail, rPassword;
    private Button rButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);
        rEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email_et);
        rPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password_et);
        rButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        rButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                attemptReg();
            }
        });
    }

    private void attemptReg(){
        final String email = rEmail.getText().toString();
        final String pass = rPassword.getText().toString();    
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //make no of login = 1
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are new, please make sure to check out the Code of Conduct for next times. You need to provide code, what you have tried yourself, etc or else you might be flagged or downvoted. Anyways, check out my answer below.

Comment: Since you are new , You need to add a field in Firestore or a field in realtime database where you keep user's info, such that it will be incremented each time user signs in and add logic in your signin method to increment it.

Comment: hi @Ethan i wouldnt say your question is too broad, Check out one question i answered  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990216/how-can-i-connect-a-device-to-my-android-firebase-database/

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself with help from the comments when the question was put on hold for several hours. Thanks for that by the way.

Create Account activity:

```
public class CreateAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText rEmail, rPassword;
private Button rButton;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference mRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);

    rEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email_et);
    rPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password_et);
    rButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    rButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            attemptReg();
        }
    });
}

private void attemptReg() {

    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mRef = database.getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).child("login_count");

    String email = rEmail.getText().toString();
    String pass = rPassword.getText().toString();

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                mRef.setValue(1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

For subsequent logins:

```
private void incrementLogincount(){
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Integer loginCount = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
        loginCount++;
        mRef.setValue(loginCount);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

}